# Send Data which I get from EJS to my other NodeJs Script (NodeJs express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, ejs

This is my Index.js file

```
const ig = require('./like');

const iglike = async() => {

   await ig.initialize();

   await ig.login('example', 'examplepass');

   await ig.liketagsprocess(***tags***);

   debugger;

};

module.exports = iglike;
```

This is my controller.js (route)

```
control.get('/like', (req, res) => {
    res.render("like");
    
});

control.post('/like', (req, res, next) => {
     let tags = req.body.likes;
     console.log(tags);
     const likeobj = require('./bin/index')(like);
     res.send(likeobj.iglike);
     next();
     res.send(tags);
     
});
```

This is my Form to get data [EJS]

```
<% (tag = ['']) %>
<form action="/like" method="POST">
    <% for (var i in tag){%>
        Tag: <input type="text" name="likes" value="<%= tag[i].likes %>"/><br><br>
        <button type="submit" value="accept">Send Tag</button><br><br><hr>
    <%} %>
</form>
```

I am a high-school student making my first web app with Node express. Sorry for the bad explanation.

***What I need to do is make the Form accept an array from the user and send it over to Index.js under "tags".***

With this code I can only accept a single string and print it in my console.

When I go to localhost/like

The form displays and after entering data it prints it in the console and executes my code in the ***index.js***

I am unable to pass my data which prints in the console over to my index.js file.

I get this error

```
(node:7140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: tags is not defined
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things you need to change:

In your index.js file, add a parameter to your function:

```js
const ig = require('./like');

const iglike = async (tags) => { // < here

  await ig.initialize();

  await ig.login('example', 'examplepass');

  await ig.liketagsprocess(tags);

  debugger;

};

module.exports = iglike;
```

In your controller.js you can import your iglike function at top of the file and use it in your route passing the tags as a parameter:

```js
const iglike = require('./bin/index');

control.get('/like', (req, res) => {
  res.render("like");
});

control.post('/like', (req, res, next) => {
  let tags = req.body.likes;
  console.log(tags);
  iglike(tags);
  next();
  res.send(tags);
});
```

In your ejs file your should change the name of the input to `likes[]` so it can be an array:

```
<% (tag = ['']) %>
<form action="/like" method="POST">
    <% for (var i in tag){%>
        Tag: <input type="text" name="likes[]" value="<%= tag[i].likes %>"/><br><br>
        <button type="submit" value="accept">Send Tag</button><br><br><hr>
    <%} %>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine now, but I am facing another problem. In my ejs file when I put likes[] and enter data suppose -- app, node -- the console displays undefined.

Comment: Are you using body-parser package? If not, you need it in express to parse the body, check express/connect top-level generic example here: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html
You need to parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Thank you again! I tried adding body-parser too still the same , please check my latest question I provided the problem in detail.